# Como colocar mais de um link em um mesmo botão?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, button, link

Como eu posso colocar mais de um link em um mesmo botão? Tipo um dropdown.
Exemplo: https://passoapasso.org.br/transparencia/

ps: Eu uso Wordpress.

Comment: Vc enviou à pergunta para o site em Português... Reescreva a pergunta na nossa língua.

Comment: Bem eu olhei o site e pelo fonte pude observar que foi feito em bootstrap. Acho que o primeiro exemplo é bem simples, vê se te ajuda.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/? Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

O site que vc citou apesar de ser um Wordpress ele usa **Bootstrap 3**, e esse é um componente simples desse *framework*, chama `button dropdowns` e vc pode ver a documentação aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns-single

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue um exemplo usando esse componente js do BS3**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Sem drop
 </button>
</div>

<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false">
  Com DropDown <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```